# Best way to download files from S3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I have around 1GB of data which my client want to download from my portal as a zip file, but in the backend the files are served from AWS S3.

Currently i am downloading all files to memory stream and zipping it, which is taking a lot of time and at times it timeout and client is not sure if request is processing as I dont have download progress in the browser.

So is there a best solution to download huge data zipped from S3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could run some code on an Amazon EC2 instance that downloads the data from Amazon S3 (very quick if in the same region), zips it, then **puts the zip back into S3.**

The user can then download it directly from S3.

If you want to get fancy, they could download via a Pre-Signed URL and you could have a lifecycle rule that deletes it after a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have little experience with S3 myself, but in general cases like this call for asynchronous processing. As in - when your user clicks "download", you initiate a background process that downloads and zips the files in some temporary location. During this, your client sees something like "preparing download, please wait". Ideally with a progress bar so that he can see that the process isn't stalled. When it's done, the download starts for real and without any timeouts since you already have the full ZIP file in a temp location.

Alternatively, see if you can streamline the whole process. Right now it sounds like you're downloading all the files to memory, creating the ZIP file in memory, and *only then* you're starting to output the first bytes to the client. You can do better. There are libraries out there that allow zipping "on-the-fly". While you're still downloading the files from S3 on one end, the other end is already spitting out ZIP file to the client. This way you don't need to keep everything in memory either.